# How to prevent one request from blocking other requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous

I've been trying to create a scenario where Request A would arrive first, but it would take a long time to process, meanwhile Request B would arrive second, but would take only a few seconds to process, and I would like for Request B to finish before Request A. However, Request A is currently blocking not just itself, but also Request B.

```
var http = require('http')
function block(){while(true){var x =2;}}
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
if(req.url=='/wait'){block();}
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('Hello Http');
  console.log(req.url)
});
server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? You can't prevent while(true); from blocking.

Comment: I want while(true) to only block request A

Comment: `while(true);` blocks forever, while it is iterating no other javascript can be run, don't use it to simulate long requests, use setTimeout or promises to delay request A

Comment: The best advice I can give you is to never create state in your server (ie. do not hold globals that change your service logic over time). The only state you have is your database. Read more about stateless web services. Also there are better ways to make something stop. Just use [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your original goal is to block a request based on some condition then there 's a better way than using a while loop.

Although it would make your code asynchronous, which will require you to handle your request a little differently.

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    if (req.url == '/wait')
        setTimeout(serveRequest, 60000);
    else
        serveRequest();

    function serveRequest() {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end('Hello Http');
        console.log(req.url);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm using the while(true) loop as a placeholder for some calculations that will be blocking, and take at least several seconds to finish. How could I prevent the blocking of a request which does not need to do these calculations, while they are currently executing for another request?

Comment: @Peristyl: You have two options. Either break up the calculations into steps that can be executed via several calls to a setTimeout/setInterval loop or spawn a child process to do the calculations

Comment: Ah, so a program is made asynchronous by passing the right to execute back and forth. I guess a child process is the way to go. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Though the request a depends on request b, there must be a rule to guarantee that request a1 and b1 are a pair, and a2 and b2 are pair, and so on.In other words, it should has a algorithm of checking wheather two request are a pair.

```
var em = new events.EventEmitter();
const EVENT_B_FINISH = 'bFinishedEvent';
var requestPairQueue = {};//key-value format,the key is the rid of request a,the value is the rid of request b.

//------request a arrive-----
var rid = //get the unique request id
//process a code......

if (requestPairQueue[rid]) {
   //the paired b request has processed,send a response directly
}
em.on(EVENT_B_FINISH,function() {
    if (requestPairQueue[rid]) {
       //the paired b request processed after a while,send a response
    }
});

//-----request b arrive----
var ridA = //the relation a request rid
var ridB = //the current b request id
//after process code....
requestPairQueue[ridA] = ridB; 
em.emit(EVENT_B_FINISH);
```